# c++ Function creates a 2-d array and returns a pointer to the 2-D array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am new to c++ and am learning to use pointers and arrays. I am having a hard time with a piece of code that is compiling and appears to be doing what it should, except the output of the pointer in the main function appears to be a memory address, so I must be missing something in the way I am calling or returning the pointer. (I hope I got the terminology right)

in my main function, I created a pointer variable and initialized it to null (professor recommended initializing all vars)

```
int** ptr1=NULL;
```

Next I set the pointer equal to my function, which creates the array

```
ptr1 = makeArray1();
```

Here is the code for my function.

```
int** makeArray1()
```

{

```
const int ROW = 2;
const int COL = 3;

int** array1 = new int* [ROW];                          //This creates the first row of cols
for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = new int[COL];               //loop to create next col of all rows
    }

for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
            {
                cout << endl << "Please enter an integer in the first matrix: ";
                cin >> array1[i][j];
            }
    }

cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < ROW;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
            {
                cout << setw(4) << array1[i][j];
            }
        cout << endl;
    }
cout << endl << endl << "In array 2 array2 = " << *array1;

return array1;
```

}

The array seems to populate with my input fine, but when I print ptr1 in the main function, it returns a memory address and not the number entered into the array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing a pointer will print the value of the pointer.  Which is a memory address.  If you want to see the value at the beginning of the 2d array you need to dereference the pointer.

Comment: How would I do this? I just looked it up and cplusplus says the * is the derefrences operator. So does this mean I just have to add a * to the return line of the function?

Comment: `cout << **ptr1` would print the first value in the 2d array.  There isn't a way to print the contents of a pointer.  You would have to iterate over the values like you did before you call `cout << endl << endl << "In array 2 array2 = " << *array1;`

Comment: thank you, that is what I was missing. I am having a hard time following where the *'s go and where they dont. I appreciate the help! MGM_Squared

Answer (score 0):

try to declare: int** array1 = new int* [ROW];
outside your function if you can

Answer (score 0):

ptr1 is a pointer. No wonder you're getting a memory adress, because a pointer is a memory adress. If you want to print the contents of the array, you would have to dereference the pointer.
Like so:

```
for(int i=0; i < ROW; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < COL; j++) {
         cout<<ptr1[i][j];
    }
}
```